# migrating data from CiviCRM to a different CRM platform

Tags: migration

I need to migrate my database from CiviCRM to a different CRM platform and need to capture as much data from Civi as possible.  What is the best way to do this to make sure I get everything?

Comment: "as much data as possible"? Do an sql dump. if that seems unhelpful (I expect it is unhelpful) then perhaps you can expand on what you are wanting to achieve. Data migration is not easy. CiviCRM lets you export lots of different entities but won't cover everything. so perhaps flesh out what data you have that matters

Comment: Curious as to why you're moving away from Civi - if you tell us what the problems are, we may be able to help it work better for you!